Prove that in a field $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \iff ad=bc$
I am new to this. Sorry if this is a stupid question.
Prove that in a field $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \iff ad=bc$
My proof:
$$\implies$$
$a \cdot d = \frac{a}{b} \cdot b \cdot d = \frac{c}{d} \cdot b \cdot d = \frac{c}{d} \cdot d \cdot b = c \cdot b = b \cdot c$
$$\impliedby$$
$\frac{a}{b} = a \cdot \frac{1}{b} = a \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{b} = ad \frac{1}{d} \frac{1}{b} = bc\frac{1}{d}\frac{1}{b} = c\frac{1}{d} = \frac{c}{d}$

Yes that's correct. You know many of this kind of proof on field or groups are "easy" like these.

@EDX Thank you! I have done similar proofs on my latest problem set and have done them all in a similar way. Therefore I wanted to check one of them.

Yes basically in a field it is rather easy to make operation because you've a lot of convenience. A field is commutative with invertible elements relative to mutliplication (except the 0) and addition. So  it is almost always basically as using real, or complex, but often richer in the content.

yeah, this is pretty much trivial. In order to avoid confuson, pick a notation system and stick to it. For example: In one row you have $\frac{c}{d}$ but then in the other $c \cdot d^{-1}$,  just write it as $\frac{c}{d}$ if you started this way.

We really need the definition of $\frac ab$ to make an informed statement about this proof. Sure, if it's $\frac ab=ab^{-1}$ then we don't go to far from high-school symbolic manipulation. If it's the definition as an element of the ring $(F\setminus{0})^{-1}F$, then you have to explain why, for any given $a,b,c,d$ such that $b\ne 0\ne d$, the condition $\exists t\in F\setminus{0},\ t(ad-bc)=0$ is equivalent to $ad=bc$.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Let $F$ be a field and let $a, b, c, d$ be such that $\frac ab = \frac cd$ (so necessarily, neither $b$ nor $d$ is $0$ in $F$). Then,
\begin{align}
a{b^{-1}} &= c{d^{-1}} \\
\iff (bd) ab^{-1} &= (bd) cd^{-1} \\
\iff adbb^{-1} &= bcdd^{-1} \\
\iff ad(1) = ad &= bc(1) = bc.
\end{align}
The first line is restating the hypothesis. The second I'm multiplying both sides by $(bd)$, then I re-group the terms (since $F-\{0\}$ forms an abelian multiplicative group). Of course, the $bb^{-1}$ and $dd^{-1}$ each become $1$, since all nonzero elements in a field have a multiplicative inverse.

Nice one , +1 , this is the gist of what I was writing in my answer !

It is Correct.
In my view , the "Presentation" could be improved.
Write it using multiple lines , where you mention what "Axiom" , "Theorem" , "Fact" you are using.
Eg 1 :
$a \cdot d = a \cdot 1 \cdot d = \frac{a}{b} \cdot b \cdot d$ , where we use the Multiplicative Identity $1 = b \cdot \frac{1}{b}$
Eg 2 :
$a \cdot d = b \cdot c = c \cdot b$ , using the Commutativity.
You will then eventually list out Associativity , Multiplicative Inverse , Etc at the "Introductory level".
That way , you will know whether what you are using is already known or whether you are jumping ahead with unproven things , due to just using your Intuition.
Eg3 :
Implicitly , you might be using $1/(xy)=(1/x)(1/y)$ , when that is not yet proven.
Eg 4 :
Accidentally , you might be using the given Claim itself , in which Case , you will have a Circularity.
Such things can be easily avoided when you use multiple lines , each listing the usage of the already proven Claims.
It will make that easier to follow too.
Later , you can skip the nitty-gritty stuff to move to the higher-level stuff , when you get more comfortable , with experience.

Please do not answer off-topic SV questions. Doing so violates of site rules.
